# Ubuntu will only boot in recovery mode ACPI error

Tags: acpi

I have a Dell G5 AMD Ryzen 5 4600h laptop that I just put Ubuntu 20.04 on. When I try and do a normal boot, I get these ACPI error messages. I can then boot in recovery mode and everything works fine, but every time I restart my laptop I get the same errors and have to reboot in recovery mode.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the vendor site for firmware updates for your machine?  Those can make a big difference with some of the Ryzen CPU machines.

Comment: I’ll give it a look. Thanks

Comment: I checked and all of my firmware is up to date. It is pretty much a brand new laptop

Comment: The initram unpacking problem might be caused by a bad install media or ISO download.  Did you hashcheck the ISO download and run a media check on the install media?

Comment: I haven’t, but I’ll try one later when I can. What would cause the download to get corrupted? I downloaded Ubuntu several times

Comment: Some ways of downloading do correction on the fly like bittorrent and zsync, but others don't.  Possibly errors are introduced when writing to disk, or to the install media.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with AMD's GPU. There are plenty of bug reports about this. This one comment has a workaround for a temporary fix: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1870971#yui_3_10_3_1_1607485120412_1778